# How does spell slot progression work with multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

I don't understand how spell slot progression works with a multi-class character.

For example, if I had a level 3 melee class, then decided to go multi-class caster, how does the spell slot progression work? Because my character is level 3, does that mean I have access to level 3 caster stats as well?

That is, would I get level 3 amount of caster slots, because my *character* is level 3, or would I only get level 1 caster slots, because I'm a *level 3 melee*, but only a *level 1 caster*?

Does it work the same way in reverse? (Level 3 caster multi-class as a melee, would I gain level 3 or level 1 abilities/skills?)

Comment: Could you quote the rules you're confused about?

Comment: @Pureferret I am not too learned with the rules currently, I just have a basic understanding that at some point, you *can* multiclass. How it works, I don't know.

Comment: @Miniman *I* don't, the group does. I only get access to it once a week though haha

Comment: In not down voting you, but I think the reason people are is because if you read the book, it's pretty obvious how it works. I think it's fair enough though that you don't have access to the rules 24/7, and that you've not gone about getting them by some other means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Multi-classing rules for spells are described in detail on page 164 and 165 of the Player's Handbook. The paragraph on page 164 that begins with the bolded text "**Spell Slots.**" tells you how to calculate what "Lvl." you should use for the purposes of consulting the table on page 165. The table, in turn, determines how many spell slots you have.

Comment: I have been going through the rules and couldn't find exact clarification on spell slots if only one of the classes is a caster. IE -  Ranger/Rogue

Comment: @Nytespade It's on the same page, PHB p.164. "If you multiclass but have the Spellcasting feature from only one class, you follow the rules as described in that class."